# Will updating nuget on one project affect the other projects in a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Will updating nuget on one project affect the other projects in a solution? I am using VS2013 update 4 via the "Manage Nuget Packages" screen to update the packages. Will this affect anything other than the selected project?

Answer (score 2):

It won't but if the projects depend on each other you will probably end up with dll versioning issues at runtime.

Although in your question you say you're using manage nuget packages, which will be solution wide, not project specific.

Comment: Hi Mike, the projects dont depend on eachother so I think they will be fine. When I am using the manage nuget packages I am getting to it by right clicking on the specific project. This says the specific project name at the top of the Manage Nuget Packages screen

Comment: You should be in ok shape then, each project keeps its own Nuget dependencies in its own packages folder.  I will say I've never done this before though.

Good luck!

Comment: I will let you know if there are any issues. Cheers